# Ghostscript - create a pdf with multiple identical pages and keep size down

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Im trying to use Ghostscript to create a PDF with multiple identical pages. I will later use this together with another multipaged PDF to stamp on unique information onto every page.

Is it possible to use Ghostscript to create such a PDF and keep the size of the final file down? Maby there is a flag that i have not noticed that can do this in a better way than the script below?

I have tried to use a regular merge command like the one below but the size of the resulting PDF grows alot and the original file size of 2,061MB merged to a 100page pdf results in a final size of 46,117MB.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64.exe"^
 -dBATCH^
 -dNOPAUSE^
 -q^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite^
 -sOutputFile=outputpdf.pdf^
 "inputpdf.pdf"^
 "inputpdf.pdf"^
 "inputpdf.pdf"(and so on 100 times)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct such a file manually easily enough, which is much smaller, by reusing the page content stream for each page.

However Ghostscript's pdfwrite device won;t do that, not least because it can't. It cannot know in advance that the page its about to receive is the same as the previous page. As a result it will create a new page content stream for each page, and create new content for it.

Note that resources (forms, patterns, colour spaces, image XObjects etc) which are used on each page *will* be reused on other pages.

However, it seems to me that you're already getting nearly a 5:1 ratio (2k * 100 pages = 200Kb, the final file is 46Kb) though in fairness a good bit of that 2Kb is 'stuff' around the page.

Without seeing your input file I can't really comment any further, but frankly I doubt its possible to make it any smaller without hand-crafting the file. What's the problem with a 46Kb file anyway ?

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your reply!
Im sorry for confusing about the filesize, i meant 2061kb, but i updated the question to MB instead. 
When this grows to use more pages, lets say 1000 of them the filesizes will start to get rather significant.
How would i go about reusing the contentstream to create the PDF?

Comment: You would need to code the PDF manually, each Page dictionary would have a /Content key pointing to the same content stream. Note that as soon as you modify any page this will break, each page must then have its own content stream, so you're back to a big file again. Not to mention the fact that a simple PDF processor might very well get confused by the fact that every page points to the same contents, if you modified one page, you might very possibly (and reasonably) end up making the same modification on every page (ie only the single content stream might be updated)